# Check is eigen matrix is empty (Eigen library C++)

Tags: c++, eigen3

Usually vectors and matrix in many libraries have method like `isEmpty()` that returns `true` if matrix's size is zero and `false` if it has some elements (no matter zero or non-zero elements).

But in Eigen library I cannot find such thing. Am I missing something?

Comment: There is no dedicated `isEmpty()` method but you can just use `EigenBase::size()`.

Comment: That is odd but thank you

Comment: It is quiet the annoyance when working with things like MISRA.